# Validar tipo de dato dentro de JSON

Tags: java, spring-boot

Intento validar el tipo de dato que se encuentra en el campo SKU, que viene dentro del siguiente JSON:

```json
    {
      "eventos": [
        {
          "idPais": 1,     
          "codigoTipoProductos": [
            "C"
          ],
          "plazos": [
            8
          ],   
          "productos": [
            {
              "sku": "1765"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Como se puede ver, este es de tipo String y paso una validación con la siguiente expresión regular:

```
String regex = "^[a-z0-9]{1,}$";
if(!Pattern.matches(regex,request.getEventos().get(0).getProductos().get(0).getSku()))
    {
        //Validación y termina proceso
    }
```

Entonces si en el JSON se pasa el parametro SKU como Integer, este responde como si estuviera correcto, por ejemplo:

```
"productos": [
    {
      "sku": 1765
    }
  ]
```

En este caso responderia que es un dato VALIDO, cuando no debería ser así.
Alguna sugerencia, por favor.

Comment: El problema es el regexp, que te valida si el campo tiene letras y/o números. Por tanto, si es integer lo valida como OK. Lo que puedes hacer es meter un try catch, y dentro del try convertir el campo SKU a Integer, si falla es porque el campo viene solo con números. Y en el catch, tratarlo como no error y trabajar con ello.

Answer (score 3):

La validación la estás haciendo después de la conversión (deserialización del JSON), así que no puedes saber si el JSON tenía un número o un String.

Un problema más profundo es que el deserializador por defecto que usa Spring Boot transforma a String cualquier dato si el atributo destino es un String, y no hay forma de cambiar este comportamiento por configuración, así que lo que nos queda es usar nuestro propio deserializador, que sea más estricto:

```java
public class StringOnlyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {
  @Override
  public String deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException {

    if (!JsonToken.VALUE_STRING.equals(parser.getCurrentToken())) {
          throw dc.wrongTokenException(parser, String.class,
               JsonToken.VALUE_STRING,
               "No es un string, no se hará conversión");
    } else {
      return parser.getValueAsString();
    }
  }
}
```

Y luego definir el módulo:

```java
@Bean
public Module customModule() {
    SimpleModule customModule = new SimpleModule();
    customModule.addDeserializer(String.class, new StringOnlyDeserializer());
    return customModule;
}
```